# How can I overcome service worker's cache

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, vite

### A legacy app presents an issue with service worker cache preventing me from serving a new app.

**short description:**

Legacy app was written in Vue, with vite-plugin-pwa (zero config service worker). When I try to point my domain to a different place - existing visitors are still served the legacy app - by the worker.

### Full problem description (made up names in "quotes"):

**Step 0**: Legacy app, written in Vue and using vite-plugin-pwa, is hosted in "blabla.hosting.bla", and DNS is pointing "example.com" to "blabla.hosting.bla".

**Step 1**: New web page is created, meant to replace legacy up. Hosted in "yadayada.hosting.yada". Changing DNS so that "example.com" now points to "yadayada.hosting.yada".

**result**: new visitors who go to "example.com" see the new page. However, past visitors who now go to "example.com" still get the old page. Why? Because the service worker is serving it to them.

**Step 2**: changed DNS so that "home.example.com" points to "yadayada.hosting.yada" (new page), "example.com" points again to the old page - "blabla.hosting.bla" and added server side redirection of "example.com" to "home.example.com".

**result**: new visitors who go to "example.com" are being redirected to "home.example.com" properly. But past visitors aren't redirected - they keep getting the cached page from the service worker.

**My conclusion** - there's no way to solve this from the server - I must do a client side solution. Specifically - to disable to the worker, or at least his cache, and do a client side redirect to "home.example.com". Let it be like this for a few weeks - and then just update the CDN like in step 1.
It's not an option to ask all the users to do a manual intervention (unregister the worker etc.)

### In general, what I have in mind is:

1. Change DNS back so that "example.com" goes to the old page  "blabla.hosting.bla" and "home.example.com" goes to the new page.
2. serve an updated version of the legacy project - with the service worker disabled / reconfigured - to prevent it from serving the old content as a fallback
3. Also, updated code will do a client side redirect to "home.example.com"
4. after a few weeks - just point "example.com" to the new homepage.

What do you think of this approach? The result will be that 100% of the visitors will have to go through the experience of a client side redirection for a while (sucks a bit, bad for SEO but whatever) - and hopefully then, once "example.com" points to the new app, the service worker will not kick in.

Do you have insights, experience with such cases?

As for how to do it - I was thinking something in the lines of (ignore the [0] - I'll use loop - just an example):

```
const registrations = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations();
await registrations[0].unregister();
document.location.href = "https://home.example.com"
```

What do you think? Will this do the work or should I completely remove the worker too? It's a Vue app and it uses vite-plugin-pwa - so if there's a better approach let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update things on the old web site. If users have your old application code cached and you do not have a way to update the cache in your service worker the new code wont work.

Sounds like you moved to a completely new domain. So the existing customers are not catching the 301 response you have on the server b/c they only see the locally cached responses.

So make an updated service worker that will